# Why do I get None instead of True/False in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that checks wether or not the characters in a string are sorted using recursion. This is what I came up with:

```
def is_sorted(x,i):
    if i >= len(x):
        return True
    elif x[i] <= x[i-1]:
        return False
    else:
        is_sorted(x,i+1)
```

I used these to test my function:

```
x = "abcadef"
y = "aabcdef"
z = "abcdef"
print is_sorted(x, 1)
print is_sorted(y, 1)
print is_sorted(z, 1)
```

I expected to get False, False, True, but instead I got None, False, None. Why? :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not returning anything in the last `else` clause. Hence the result.

```
def is_sorted(x,i):
    if i >= len(x):
        return True
    elif x[i] <= x[i-1]:
        return False
    else:
        return is_sorted(x,i+1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def is_sorted(x,i):
...     if i >= len(x):
...         return True
...     elif x[i] <= x[i-1]:
...         return False
...     else:
...         return is_sorted(x,i+1)
... 
>>> x = "abcadef"
>>> y = "aabcdef"
>>> z = "abcdef"
>>> print is_sorted(x, 1)
False
>>> print is_sorted(y, 1)
False
>>> print is_sorted(z, 1)
True
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple, yet so helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the function to pass it up the recursive chain

```
def is_sorted(x,i):
    if i >= len(x):
        return True
    elif x[i] <= x[i-1]:
        return False
    else:
        return is_sorted(x,i+1) # <---- Here
```